# Is it possible to put a "link" on text message that opens up a native app on the phone?

Tags: swift, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, ios5

So a user clicks a link or something on a text message
and an app opens up.  Its important that it opens up a "particular" page
of an app. It might open lets say an "about us" page on an app.
If something like this is possible how can it be done?

Thank You

Comment: If you have more specific questions update it or ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to do this and the term you'd look for is "deep linking".  It also works for Window phones.  For an overview, see: [App Indexing and Deep Links](http://marketingland.com/library/mobile-marketing-news/app-indexing-deep-links).